# How to change the renaming pattern when there are duplicate files

Tags: python, django

Let's say I upload a file to my Django App (`A.pdf`)

Over time I realize that that file contains an error. I want to upload that file back to my website and keep the old file, but I want the file name to change to `A(1).pdf`

I implemented a drag & drop system with `Dropzone.js` and everything is working but, when a file is duplicated the system assigns new names randomly.

This is an example:

[image]
[image]

How can I get rid of the `_QXjmarl` string and replace it with `(N)` pattern? `E.g. (1), (2), (3)...(45), (N)`

`Dropzone.js`:

```
var Drop = Dropzone.options.DidDropzone = {

    autoProcessQueue: false, //stops from uploading files until user submits form
    paramName: "filename", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 1024, // Maximum size of file that you will allow (MB)
    clickable: true, // This allows the dropzone to select images onclick
    acceptedFiles: '.psd, .csv, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, application/csv, application/docx, application/excel, application/msword, application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.msexcel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, text/anytext, text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, text/plain, image/*, video/*,', //accepted file types
    maxFiles: 20, //Maximum number of files/images in dropzone
    parallelUploads: 20,
    previewTemplate: '<div class="dz-preview dz-image-preview">'+
                        '<div class="dz-image">'+
                        '<img data-dz-thumbnail />'+
                        '</div>'+

                      '<div class="dz-details">'+
                        '<div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>'+
                        '<div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>'+
                      '</div>'+

                      '<div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>'+
                      '<div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>'+
                      '<div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>'+
                    '</div>',
    init: function(){

        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#image-btn")
        var url = $('#DidDropzone').attr("action")
        myDropzone = this;

        //process the queued images on click
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            myDropzone.processQueue();
            $('#fileUploadModal').modal('hide'); 
        });

        //fire the images to url
        myDropzone.on("processing", function(file) {
          myDropzone.options.url = url;
        });

        //clear the dropzone when complete
        myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
            myDropzone.removeFile(file);
        });
    },
    success: function(file, json){

        // alert("Perfect! Now visit your gallery...")      
        
    },
}
```

`views.py`:

```
@login_required
def project_page(request):
    context = {}
    context['nbar'] = projects
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.FILES)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file_hist = form.save(commit=False)
            file_hist.user = request.user
            file_hist.save()
            return render(request, 'project_page.html', context)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'project_page.html', context)
```

`project_page.html`:

```
<form action="project_page" id="DidDropzone" class="dropzone dz" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="dz-message">
        <div class="dz-message2">Choose files</div>
        or drag them here.
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a predefined method in Django to change the pattern of duplicate files? I have not found anything on the internet nor do I know what part of the code is renaming the files.

What is the most pythonic way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own storage class and overwrite the method [get_alternative_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-file-storage/#django.core.files.storage.get_alternative_name) to change this behaviour

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


class MyStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_alternative_name(self, file_root, file_ext):
        n = get_next_n(file_root)  # Needs to be implemented
        return f'{file_root}({n}){file_ext}'
```

Then add the [setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-file-storage)

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'my_app.storage.MyStorage'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and shed some light.

So I can keep all the default storage functionalities included in Django, right? Here in the example that you provided, we would just be overriding the get_alternative_name method. What exactly does the part `# Needs to be implemented` have to do?

Comment: Yes, this will have all the same functionality as the default storage, just the single method is overridden. You'll need to implement some function that can detect what the next name/number should be from the given file name, would have to handle numbers being present already or not so may not be quite so simple as it first appears